# Scaling CakePHP Version 2.3.0

Tags: apache, cakephp, mysqli, cakephp-2.0, scalability

I'm beginning a new project using CakePHP. I like the "auto-magic" features, I think its a good fit for the project. I'm wondering about the potential to scale CakePHP to several million IP hits a day.  and hundreds of thousands of database writes and reads a day. Also about 50,000 to 500,000 users, often with 3000 concurrently using the site. I'm making use of heavy stored procedures to offset this, and I'm accessing several servers including a load balancer.

I'm wondering about the computational time of some of the auto-magic and how well Cake is able to assist with session requests making many db hits. Has anyone has had success with cake running from a single server array setup with this level of traffic? I'm not using the cloud or a distributed database (yet). I'm really worried about potential bottlenecks with using this framework. I'm interested in advice from anyone who has worked with Cake in production. I've reseached, but I would love a second opinion. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem but optimization is up to you.

- There are different cache methods available you can implement, memcache, redis, full page caching... All of that is supported by cacke already. What you cache and where is up to you.
- For searching you could try elastic search to speedup things
- There are before dispatcher filters to by pass controller instantiation (you might want to do that in special cases, check the asset filter for example)
- Use nginx not apache

Also I would not start with over optimizing and over-thinking this before any code is written, start well, think about caching but when you start to come across bottleneck analyse and fix them. Otherwise you'll waste a lot of time with over optimization before you even have written anything that works.

Cake itself is very fast. Just to proof the bullshit factor of these fancy benchmarks some frameworks do we did one using a dispatcher filter to "optimize" it and even beat Yii who seems to be pretty eager to show how fast it is, but benchmarks are pointless, specially in a huge project where so many human made fail can be introduced.

Comment: Thank you, yeah that's what I thought. I just wanted the opinion of someone in the know. Caching is a really good idea, that it something I have not yet looked far enough into.